# selecting an a default date today date in atextbox using ajax calendar control

Tags: asp.net, ajax

i have a textbox, and i am using ajax calendar control. By default the textbox should  show today's date, for example, 04/08/2009, and if the user wants to change the date he  can click on the textbox to pop up an ajax calendar control. There, he can select a date.

By default, the textbox should always show today's date.
thank you.

Answer (score 2):

paste this code in the code behind file(i.e the .vb file) umder the calenderextender1 load event...!

```
CalendarExtender1.SelectedDate = DateTime.Now.Date
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding this in the code behind will work:

```
txtBox.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
```

See:

- [MSDN: DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring.aspx)